# Force progress bar component to re-render after progress prop has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**How can I force a component to re-render after a passed-in prop has changed?**

*Premise: On my base page, I have a progress bar. From that base page, the user can access a number of modal pages. The progress bar should visualise how many modals the user has viewed.*

In principle, most of it works. The only problem is that my progress bar component does not re-render my visual progress bar when the passed-in `progress` prop changes.

```
<ProgressBar 
    progress={ this.props.progress } 
/>
```

The progress bar component itself is aware of the change and will happily re-render a text field that prints the value of `progress` to reflect the updated value. However, it will not re-render the visual progress bar (a series of view components with styling) in a way that reflects the changed prop. The text field changes, the views do not.

Here's my code. Could it be that I need to repeat the calculations I do in `ComponentDidMount()` in some kind of update function as well?

```
// Progress Bar component
export default class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

    state = {
        // define some variables
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // do some math using this.props.progress and state
        // to calculate the percentage etc that the views use to
        // display the length of the progress bar
    }

    componentWillUpdate( prevProps, prevState ) {
        // I tried repeating the above calculations in here as well 
        // but anything I place in here will result in error message:
        // Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded...
    }

    render() {
        // a number of views that create a visual progress bar
        // entirely dependent on calculated values, i.e. not directly
        // referencing this.props.progress
    }
```

}

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: don't save the passed in prop in state

Comment: if it's updating the text field then it is re-rendering, sounds like the problem lies in your implementation of the bar itself... can you add that to your question?

Comment: @JuniusL. I am not saving the passed in prop in state.

Comment: try adding `getDerivedStateFromProps()` this's called when passed pros change.

Comment: I have added `componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps )` and within I repeat all calculations for my progress bar, but using the `nextProps` values. So far, this appears to do the trick.

Comment: `componentwillreceiveprops` was deprecated use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Answer (score 1):

When the passed props change `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is called before render method. In here you can compare the current state with the new data and return an object or null to update nothing.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
```

Comment: The problem with that method is that within it, I can't call my regular functions using `this.`, can I?

Comment: you can `getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) => {}`

Comment: call your function and if you don't want to update state return null.

Comment: I mean because it's `static`?

Answer (score 0):

> However, it will not re-render the visual progress bar (a series of view components with styling) in a way that reflects the changed prop. The text field changes, the views do not.

This proves that this component rerenders quite well. No need to search for a magic bullet, another way for force rerender. **Component rerenders on prop change.**

```
render() {
    // a number of views that create a visual progress bar
    // entirely dependent on calculated values, i.e. not directly
    // referencing this.props.progress
}
```

There we need more data/code - **this is the source of problems**. Construction of child components can lead to 'stop rerender process propagation down the tree'. **If any of direct child is not rerendering than deeper children won't rerender.**

Answer (score -2):

A re-render can only be triggered if state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. The component gets the updated state and React decides if it should re-render the component.

so component you will pass a state if state you will change any where its make effects on render 
class Progress extends React.Component {

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(() => {

            progress:true
        });
    }, 1000);
}

render() {

    return (<div>{this.state.progress ? <div> true </div>: <div>false</div>}</div>);
}
```

}